# iPhone: Roaming MCC

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, roaming, mcc

Is there a possibility to retrieve the "actual" Mobile Country Code of the iPhone?

If I use the conventional method over the CTCarrier I only receive the MCC of the SIM-Card, but I want the Mobile Country Code of the Roaming Provider.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible in the current iOS SDK.

Comment: Is it maybe possible using functions of a private API?

(The app will not be published into the App-Store)

Comment: Receiving the current country (ID) the user is located, would be also sufficient..

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe this is possible with a private API, but you can use a third party service such as http://ipinfo.io, which I built. Here's the standard API response, which will include carrier details in the org field:

```
$ curl ipinfo.io/24.32.148.1 
{
    "ip": "24.32.148.1",
    "hostname": "doc-24-32-148-1.pecos.tx.cebridge.net",
    "city": "Pecos",
    "region": "Texas",
    "country": "US",
    "loc": "31.3086,-103.5892",
    "org": "AS7018 AT&T Services, Inc.",
    "postal": "79772"
}
```

Custom packages are available that also include the full mnc/mcc details for mobile IPs though. See http://ipinfo.io/developers for details.

Comment: while on wireless or proxied connection the information is not correct at all